# django template error using sct

Tags: django, django-templates

Iam newly using SCT tools in my project. In the board,when i try to display only the names - Politics, IT by using the code `{% sphboard_displayCategories rootCategories.name %}`.iam getting the error as
 `Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [name] in u'[<Category: politics>, <Category: IT>]'`

If i use `{% sphboard_displayCategories rootCategories %}`,iam getting the entire details of the Politics and IT. But I need to display only the names with url path. Anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know SCT tools, but you could return:

```
rootNames = map(lambda x: x.name, rootCategories)
```

from your view and use those (assuming SCT just expects strings). You obviously can't access ".name" on a list, this won't work in python either, you have to access name on the individual objects in the list.